# How to check the type of a list if inheritance is used

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a C# program that creates a List, of object Task, the object Task is a base class and many other inherit from it. What I want to is compare the type of one of the object within said list to see which form should be opened in order to edit it.

This is the code I have already created.

```
private void itemEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int edi = taskNameBox.SelectedIndex;
        Task checkTask = todoList.ElementAt(edi);

        if(checkTask.GetType is Note)
        {
            noteBuilder editNote = new noteBuilder(todoList);
            editNote.Show();
        }

        else if(checkTask.GetType is extendedTask)
        {
            extendedTaskBuilder editTask = new extendedTaskBuilder(todoList);
            editTask.Show();
        }

        else if(checkTask.GetType is Reminder)
        {
            reminderBuilder editReminder = new reminderBuilder(todoList);
            editReminder.Show();
        }

        else if (checkTask.GetType is Appointment)
        {
            appointmentBuilder editAppointment = new appointmentBuilder(todoList);
            editAppointment.Show();
        }
    }
```

On a secondary note would it be easier if instead of passing the list between the forms and generating a new object of the form that display information that I instead pass a single object between forms and just update the form every time a new element is added to the list.

Many thanks

Comment: why are you passing the whole todolist to the builders when you only check one of the contained items for the type? Do you want to edit the list or just the one selected item?

Comment: @Marcel probably he isn't passing it. Could be a member variable. WillzSawyer, you have got the answer actually.

Comment: OK, but then it is even more confusing. To me the question is quite unclear, and the accepted answer does not match the question in a reasonable way. Ill' give -1 to the question.

Comment: I'm just editing the selected item, however I was simply passing the list as I was just testing to see if the form would generate as I could see the error marking on Visual Studio it just wouldn't tell me what the error was about. I was secretly hoping that it would run without error, but it did.

Comment: this question is pretty clear and accepted answer answers to atleast the main question of OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking like this:

```
if (checkTask is Note)
{

}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a base class for all types you are now switching between and call a virtual (abstract) method?

Put all code now in the if in the overridden abstract method.

Advantages:
- The intelligence of the switch is within the classes where it belongs.
- When a new type is added you get a compiler error to also add this feature to the new type.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead of doing that series of ‘if’ clauses, you use inheritance to achieve what ou need. First you create a virtual method in your base class. A virtual method means it won't have any implementation in the base class, only the declaration:

```
public class Task
{
    (...)
    public virtual void ShowEditForm(IList todoList);
    (...)
}
```

Then you create the child class methods (I'm assuming the todoList object is a IList, but just change it if it is not).

```
public class Note: Task
{
    (...)
    public override void ShowEditForm(IList todoList)
    {
        (new noteBuilder(taskToEdit)).Show();
    }
    (...)
}

public class Reminder: Task
{
    (...)
    public override void ShowEditForm(IList todoList)
    {
        (new reminderBuilder(taskToEdit)).Show();
    }
    (...)
}
```

I didn't write all the classes, but I think you've got the idea. To call the method, you just call the method from Task class, and the right method will be executed:

```
int edi = taskNameBox.SelectedIndex;
Task checkTask = todoList.ElementAt(edi);
checkTask.ShowEditForm(todoList);
```

This way, when you want to create new types of Task, you just have to create the child class, with the proper method, and the inheritance system will do the rest.

One more thing, the override keyword in the child method declaration is important, because it says to the compiler that this method should be called even if you call it from the BaseClass.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what's the difference between IList and List<Task>?

Comment: An IList is a interface to most kind of collections, like List<T>, ArrayList, SortedList and others. A List<task> is a List object. But in the example it would be best to use the real type of the object, I just put put IList because the type wasn't especified in the example.

Answer (score 1):

First, to your second note. What you are talking about doing is having a global object that all forms refer to in some parent. That can work, however you will need to make sure there is some mechanism in place that makes sure all of the forms are synchronized when one changes, and this can get messy and a bit of a mess to maintain. I am not necessarily advocating against it per say, but just adding words of caution when considering it :)

As to your posted code, it would probably be better to turn this into a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) approach, where all forms inherit from a base class/interface which has a `Show` method. Then all you need to do is call `checkTask.Show(todoList);`. If you do not want that coming from the `Task`, then you could have your forms all inherit from the above base and you could use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that takes in the `Task` and `list` and returns the appropriate form on which you simply call `form.Show();`

Answer (score 1):

Code like this is difficult to maintain, you are probably better off abstracting this out, like so (assuming `Task` is not the one included in .net):

```
public interface IBuilder
{
     void Show();
}

public abstract class Task
{
    // ...
    public abstract IBuilder GetBuilder(TaskList todoList);
    // ...
}

public class Note : Task
{
    public override IBuilder GetBuilder(TaskList todoList)
    {
        return new noteBuilder(todoList);
    }
    // ...
}

// etc.

private void itemEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int edi = taskNameBox.SelectedIndex;
    Task checkTask = todoList.ElementAt(edi);

    IBuilder builder = checkTask.GetBuilder(todoList);
    builder.Show();
}
```

Alternately, you can use an injection pattern:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    protected Task(Func<TaskList, IBuilder> builderStrategy)
    {
        _builderStrategy = builderStrategy;
    }

    public IBuilder GetBuilder(TaskList todoList))
    {
        return _builderStrategy(todolist);
    }
}

public class Note : Task
{
    public Note(Func<TaskList, IBuilder> builderStrategy) : base(builderStrategy) {}
}

// ...
note = new Note(x => return new noteBuilder(x));
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I really understand the concept of the abstract class. I was under the impression from what I had been taught that you can't create object of abstract classes. Although its possible that we've been taught this so we don't struggle with complexity to much.

Comment: No, you cannot create an instance of the abstract class, but, presumably, you would be creating an instance of one of the classes that inherit from it.  The idea here is to move the responsibility of creating the builder to the classes, so you do not need to have the long if..else chain you described in your question.

Comment: Well I am creating a list of the Base class, so I am creating a list of the base class object. Or am I misunderstanding how lists work and I am actually creating a structure that will hold object that inherit from the base class?

Comment: You are creating a list that holds objects of a certain type.  An inherited class is also of the type of its base.